# How to prove that a set of derived closed-form equations for a heat exchanger do not violate the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, thermal-conductivity

Recently I have been working on a problem involving a cross-flow heat exchanger (Two fluids flow orthogonal to each other on either side of a separating wall and exchange heat with each other through this wall). As a result, I have derived analytical expression to describe the temperature distributions for the hot (loses heat), cold (gains heat) fluids and the separating wall between them. I would like to prove that these equations do not violate the second law of thermodynamics . Can someone provide some guiding points on how to achieve this mathematically ?

Comment: The question is very vague. Therefore I am going to vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the overall heat exchanger, the rate of entropy flowing out minus the rate of entropy flowing in must equal the rate of entropy generation within the exchanger.  This must be greater than zero in order to satisfy the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Thanks ! If I have the temperature distributions of the three quantities i.e. $T_h, T_c, T_w$, can you elaborate a bit more on how the entropy flow will be calculated ? I mean what equations should be used, I can also use a reference. I must mention here that my equations do not involve velocity of the fluids, only the dimensions of the exchanger and the inlet temperatures.

Comment: And obviously the derived equations can predict the fluid outlet temperatures.

Comment: How can you calculate the outlet temperatures without knowing the flow rates?  The basis for doing the entropy balance on the heat exchanger is given in Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, probably Chapter 6.  http://dl.booktolearn.com/ebooks2/engineering/mechanical/9781119391760_Fundamentals_of_Engineering_Thermodynamics_9th_e857.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I think my statement about velocity came out wrongly. I do have mass flow rate (calculated using velocity) in my equations. What I meant is that my problem solution does not incorporate details of velocity profiles in the duct. Thanks again !